# Push-pull Amplifier Class AB

Tags: amplifier, push-pull

I am new to electronics and I am trying to build an audio amplifier with an input signal of 100mV @ 60 hz using 12V as VCC and expect an output of 70-75W power.

I have the following circuit:
[image]

I copied this one from my notes and simulated it just to find out that it does not amplify. I believe there is something wrong with the biasing. What could be the problem?

Comment: You're in luck, you build something (luckily in a simulator so nothing can blow up :-) ) and it doesn't work. Now you can learn something ! Why do you believe the biasing is not OK ? (please motivate) have you checked it ? What should it be ? Are the (DC) currents and voltages what you expect them to be  ? And what do you expect ?

Comment: You're definitely not going to get 70-75W with a 1.225k load.

Comment: That is correct, now why would that be ? What would you need ? Questions, questions ....

Comment: I thought because it has very small output power, somehow it might not be working on active mode. Thanks all

Comment: If you're not willing to understand the how and why, then why would you try to build this thing. Why not get some module on eBay that you just hook-up and it works ? Saves you all this trouble. I mean something like this: http://www.ebay.nl/itm/Class-AB-MOSFET-L7-Audio-power-amplifier-board-KIT-MONO-300-350W-NEW-/121097014766?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_15&hash=item1c31f1cdee

Comment: I am willing to know how to build the thing. I just don't know yet what specific questions should I ask. Or if I may ask how to build a 70-75W audio amplifier using BJTs with minimal stages your help would be very much appreciated

Comment: If you just want to build the thing then find a design and build that. Making your own designing and building that isn't something you can do with little electronics knowledge and a few questions answered by someone else ! The fact that in your schematic above you expect 70 W in a 1225 ohm resistor while using a 12 V supply proves to me that you are far too inexperienced to design your own power amplifier. You want to learn electronics, excellent then learn ! But trying to design something way above your head is a waste of time. Sorry, that's just how it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its not the biasing - in fact there is no problem.
That circuit is not a *voltage* amplifier, its a *current* amplifier - the key feature being that both of your transistors are configured as emitter-followers (gain ~ 1).

What you have there is a common configuration for the output stage of an audio amplifier because it can drive lots of current into your speaker.

You need to add a voltage gain stage in front of it in order to amplify your 100mV signal into something that the output stage can use.
The easiest way is to cheat and use an opamp...